# What does it mean to say "defining law of a covariant tensor of order two"?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking at covariant differentiation of a vector and in my notes it says the transformation law is $$\bar T^i = T_r \frac{\partial x ^r}{\partial \bar x^i}$$

What is the transformation law?

In my notes it also outlines the steps to deducing the defining law of a covariant tensor of order two.

This is given as $$\frac{\partial \bar T^i}{\partial \bar x^k}- \bar \Gamma^t _{ik} \bar T_t =\bigg(\frac{\partial T_r}{\partial x^s} -\Gamma ^t _{rs}  T_t \bigg) \frac{\partial x ^r}{\partial \bar x^i} \frac{\partial x^s}{\partial \bar x^k}$$

> What is the defining law of a covariant tensor of order two?

Answer (score 0):

One is writting the new components $\bar{T}^i$ in terms of the linear combination $\sum_rT_r\dfrac{\partial x^r}{\partial \bar{x}^i}$, for the first question.